# Installing ImageMagick on Win/PHP 5.4

Tags: php, apache, imagemagick

I need ImageMagick on PHP 5.4. Windows, both Apache and IIS7.

I've downloaded ImageMagick-6.8.1-9-Q16-x86-dll.exe and http://valokuva.org/~mikko/imagick-php54-php53.tgz

But I get an error upon Apache restart:

> PHP.EXE NO ENTRY POINT FOUND:
>
> The procedure entry point php_checkuid_ex could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll

Comment: and which versions of php, windows, apache, iis...? 64 or x86?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is obviously a problem with the php extension. I use the build from http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/ with PHP 5.4.10 and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Imagemagick and Imagick are two different things. Imagick is an API in php for Imagemagick.

Use the Imagemagick exe file to install Imagemagick then you need to find an Imagick.dll that will work with your setup - not as easy as it seems! php version as well as how it was compiled.

What do you want to use; Imagemagick through php and command line or Imagick directly through php?

I use Imagemagick on XAMPP and once Imagemagick is installed php finds it automaticaly. Do not forget if you are working with pdf files you will need to install ghostscript as well.

Comment: I tried to use Imagick directly through php. I've downloaded and installed ImageMagick . I've chosen ImageMagick-6.8.8-10-Q16-x86-dll.exe then I've downloaded the php extension and I've moved the dll extension I just downloaded to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\ext\ and added `extension=php_imagick.dll`, to the extensions lists. restarted Apache. I restarted the wampserver. ImageMagick extensions now shows enabled on the list. But by doing a quick test returns "Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found". any idea?

Comment: hi bonzo i just installed imagemagic and ghost script but xampp is not detecting imagic classess